# Android, background service with UI manager

Tags: java, android, service

I am having logistic problem. I am not very familiar with android/java  much (I've made some simple UI app displaying bluetooth devices but that;s about it).
Was considering react native, but doesn't seem to fit.
I want to make background service that will automatically connect to bluetooth device and will process data in and out, also needs to run indefinitely and after boot.
But I also  need some UI for settings, like select Bluetooth device, or transmit custom message through that service /BT connection.

Is that even possible?
I've seen apps like that, e.g custom notifications app.
How to approach that, is it possible to communicate with service from UI?

I just need some direction, or keywords, not looking for ready solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XML resource file layouts for android.  That is your UI.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout
Read this, and if you're not familiar with android yet, favorite developer.android.com because its your best friend right now.

You're going to be learning XML just as you learn Java in android.  It's used everywhere.

Example layout code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/greetings"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMainMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainheader" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMortgageCalculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mortgage Calculator"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMainMenu"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainheader" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMortgageCalculator"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainheader" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/homePageDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/homeDescription"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonMortgageCalculator"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tobiasmealeyhouse"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Then in your main.activity:
Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Go to Main Menu
        Button mainmenu = findViewById(R.id.buttonMainMenu);
        mainmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent goToMenuIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(goToMenuIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        //Go to Mortgage Calculator
        Button mortgagecalculator = findViewById(R.id.buttonMortgageCalculator);
        mortgagecalculator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mortgageCalculatorIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MortgageCalculator.class);
                startActivityForResult(mortgageCalculatorIntent,0);
            }
        });

        //Go to test
        Button test = findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent goToTestIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Test.class);
                startActivityForResult(goToTestIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Essentially, you're going to build a UI with buttons and EditText boxes that are objects created in your XML file, then you will program them in java to do what you want as far as communicating.

Comment: I should be more specific, I did make Android app already with UI, some simple one but still. The bit I don't know yet is how to make a background service that can be also managed from UI, but also will run in background all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since I misunderstood you the first time, I'm just going to leave that answer up and write a new one altogether.

I think you should start by looking into homescreen widgets then:
[https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html#:~:text=One%20exciting%20new%20feature%20in%20the%20Android%201.5,details%20about%20a%20song%20playing%20in%20the%20background](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html#:%7E:text=One%20exciting%20new%20feature%20in%20the%20Android%201.5,details%20about%20a%20song%20playing%20in%20the%20background).

There's an article about it that gives you the UI.  Then you can interface with your backend service from the widget on your users home screens via a widget.

After reading about widgets, and getting an idea about your widget design and what it needs to do:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_bluetooth.htm
This gets you started on how bluetooth data transfers work.  You'll be using libraries likethe bluetooth adapter and calling specific classes for dealing with your bluetooth function of the app.

Lastly, if you need backend storage look into SQLite Databases that android uses for on device storage.